# Проблема с сохранением в QSettings

Tags: c++, qt

Необходимо реализовать сохранения состояния программы.

Имеется `QTableWidget` с занесенными в ее ячейки `QLineEdit`:

```
m_doubleValidator.setNotation(QDoubleValidator::StandardNotation); //стандартная нотация
for (int j = 1; j < ui->SG_Uvn->columnCount(); j++)
    for (int i = 1; i <= ui->SG_Uvn->rowCount(); i++) 
    {
        QLineEdit * tableline = new QLineEdit;
        tableline->setValidator( &m_doubleValidator);
        ui->SG_Uvn->setCellWidget(i, j, tableline);
    }
```

Дальше мне необходимо чтобы при повторном запуске программы значения в ячейках таблицы были теми же, что и при последнем закрытии программы.

Загрузка:

```
QList<QLineEdit*> linelist = findChildren <QLineEdit*>();
for (auto i: linelist) 
{
    qDebug() << i->objectName() << " | " << QString::number(settings2->value(fileName + QString("/") + i->objectName()).toDouble());
    i->setText( QString::number(settings2->value(fileName + QString("/") + i->objectName()).toDouble()) );
}
```

Сохранение:

```
QList<QLineEdit*> linelist = findChildren<QLineEdit*>();
for (auto i: linelist) 
{
    settings->setValue("settings/" + i->objectName(), i->text());
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы значения возвращались на свои места?

В ф-ции загрузки `i->objectName()` пустой...

Comment: Я могу предположить что можно сохранять что то на подобие : SG_Unv|2|2=5,т.е SG_Unv это название таблицы,и 2|2 следовательно строки и столбцы.Т.е как то парсить.Но вопрос как же тогда обратиться к таблице используя только ее название в QString?

Comment: Таблица из QLineEdit - это сильно. Не думали базу данных использовать? Какую-нибудь SQLite например, которые в виде файлов существует. Сам QSettings он скорее для хранения конфигов, наборов пар ключ->значение. В QSettings тогда можно записывать путь до файла с БД, хранящей ваши таблицы.

Comment: чтобы objectName() не был пустой нужно его явно указывать при создании. Например tableline - > setObjectName("lineEdit1")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сохранить в QSettings кол-во строк и столбцов таблицы, затем сохранять значения в виде "№строки_№столбца" = "значение" и при загрузке парсить этой строку, и вставлять значение в соответствующую ячейку.